# How to use Dart SpeechSynthesis class?

Tags: dart, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I'm unable to construct a SpeechSynthesis object using Dart SpeechSynthesis class. Dart editor complains: "The class 'SpeechSynthesis' does not have a default constructor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
main() {
  var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  u.text = 'Hello World';
  u.lang = 'en-US';
  u.rate = 1.2;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(u);
}
```

See [the SpeechSynthesis Interface](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#tts-section) for more details on the API.

Comment: My tests tend to show that not all the API is implemented for now.